# pass string in array

Tags: c, arrays, string

I am trying to pass strings (lines of text file) into arrays (`array` for `f1` and `array2` for `f2`). When I just print the `buffer` `buffer2`, the lines come up just fine. When I try to pass them using `strcpy` the program crashes with no apparent reason. I have tried the following:

- Using a two dimensional array with no avail
- Working with methods and tried to return char and THEN pass it to the array, so I can avoid this sloppy code, but this will do for now.

I am using windows 7 x64, with DEV-C++.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    char *arrayF1[20] ;
    char *arrayF2[20] ;
    int i = 0; 
    int size = 1024, pos;
    int c;
    int lineCount = 0;
    char *buffer = (char *)malloc(size);
    char *buffer2 = (char *)malloc(size);
    char *array[100];
    char *array2[100];


    if (argc!=3)
    {
       printf("\nCommand Usage %s filename.txt filename.txt\n", argv[0]); 
    }
    else
    {        
        FILE *f1 = fopen(argv[1], "r");
        FILE *f2 = fopen(argv[2], "r");

        if(f1) 
         {
          do { // read all lines in file
            pos = 0;
            do{ // read one line
              c = fgetc(f1);
              if(c != EOF) buffer[pos++] = (char)c;
              if(pos >= size - 1) { // increase buffer length - leave room for 0
                size *=2;
                buffer = (char*)realloc(buffer, size);
              }
            }while(c != EOF && c != '\n');
            lineCount++;
            buffer[pos] = 0;
            // line is now in buffer 
            strcpy(array[i], buffer);
            printf("%s", array[i]);
            //printf("%s", buffer);
            i++;
          } while(c != EOF); 
          printf("\n");
          fclose(f1);           
        }
        printf("%d\n",lineCount);
        free(buffer);    

        lineCount=0;
        i=0;
        if (f2)
        {
          do { // read all lines in file
            pos = 0;
            do{ // read one line
              c = fgetc(f2);
              if(c != EOF) buffer2[pos++] = (char)c;
              if(pos >= size - 1) { // increase buffer length - leave room for 0
                size *=2;
                buffer2 = (char*)realloc(buffer, size);
              }
            }while(c != EOF && c != '\n');
            lineCount++;
            buffer2[pos] = 0;
            // line is now in buffer 
            strcpy(array2[i], buffer);
            //printf("%s", buffer2);
            printf("%s", array2[i]);
            i++;
          } while(c != EOF); 
          printf("\n");
          fclose(f2);           
        }
        printf("%d\n",lineCount);
        free(buffer2);    
        }//end first else
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't allocated any memory for the arrays in `array`. You'll need to do that before you can copy the strings there.

```
array[i] = malloc(pos + 1);

if (array[i] == NULL) {
    // handle error
}

strcpy(array[i], buffer);
printf("%s", array[i]);
```

Answer (score 1):

To `strcpy()` to a `char*`, you need to have already allocated memory for it. You can do this by making static `char` arrays:

```
char array[100][50];   //Strings can hold up to 50 chars
```

or you can use pointers and dynamically allocate them instead.

```
char *array[100];

for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    array[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * 50);    //Up to 50 chars

...

for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
   free(array[i]);          //Delete when you're finished
```

After allocating it with one of those methods, it's safe to write to it with `strcpy()`.

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like you allocated the arrays on the stack but failed to ensure that they'd be big enough, since each has size exactly `100`. Since you don't know how big they'll be, you can either allocate them dynamically (using @JohnKugelman's solution) or wait to declare them until after you know what their sizes need to be (i.e., how long the strings are that they need to hold).

Answer (score 1):

> the program crashes with no apparent reason

There is always a reason :)

This line:

```
char *array[100];
```

Creates an array of 100 pointers to characters.

Then this line:

```
strcpy(array[i], buffer);
```

Tries to copy your `buffer` to the i<sup>th</sup> pointer. The problem is that you never allocated any memory to those pointers, so `strcpy()` crashes. Just this:

```
array[i] = malloc(strlen(buffer)+1);
strcpy(array[i], buffer);
```

will resolve that error.